# I am new to Verilog, If initial block can not be synthesized then how to initialize registers without resetting please someone explain

Tags: verilog

Suppose in this module the array must contain the following values so that I can proceed rest of the work, so how to initialize the array at the initial stage.

```
module mem();

  reg i;
  reg [9:0] valueI[0:2];

  initial begin
    valueI[0]=10'b1111111111;
    valueI[1]=10'b0000011111;
    valueI[2]=10'b1111100000;
  end

endmodule
```

If initial block can not be synthesized then how to initialize registers without resetting please someone explain

Comment: Can you please be more precise in what you ask for?

Comment: you **cannot** initialize them without resetting in hardware.

Comment: So Mr serge you want to say I need to use reset like the following code if(reset) begin valueI[0]=10'b1111111111 end

Comment: something like `always @(posedge cllk) if (reset) begin value <= reset-value';end else begin value <= real-value;  end`

Answer (score 0):

While you can't do this in general, on Xilinx FPGAs for example, the Verilog initial statement will set the initial value of registers after FPGA configuration.